# Understanding how does certificate validation work

Tags: tls, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-revocation

I'm using Wireshark for better understanding how is a SSL connection established. I captured the traffic of visiting three pages: reddit, facebook and this one. All HTTPS of course.

Reddit: after the server sends the `Certificate`, it sends a `Certificate Status` with the response of the OCSP server. Why is the server sending this information? Shouldn't be the client the one who queries the OCSP for knowing the status of the server's certificate?

Security SE: I see there is no validation at all. After the client receives the certificate, they exchange the symmetric key and the encrypted channel is established. Why there is no validation?

Facebook: after the SSL connection is established, i.e. after the encrypted channel is created, the client queries the OCSP server. Why doesn't it query the OCSP before establishing the connection?

PS: if someone is interested in the captures, just run Wireshark, visit those sites and use `ssl.handshake` filter.

Comment: I think you're seeing OSCP Stapling in action: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCSP_stapling

Comment: NB There is a great article on [the first few milliseconds of a HTTPS connection](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html) (from 2009).

Comment: You don't see any validation on this site as, chances are, that your browser/OS has already cached the revocation information (OCSP or CRL) during a previous visit.

Comment: @garethTheRed tried in a VM in which I've never visited the site, no validation either.

Comment: Is the browser in the VM configured to use OCSP?

Comment: @garethTheRed yes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Validation** is about making sure that a certificate is genuine. The goal is to know whether the public key you see is really owned by the server you intend to talk to. This validation entails a lot of steps, described [there](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-6) in all their gory details; most of them are completely local to the client machine, so you won't see them show up in any way with network traces. In fact that's the whole idea of certificates: to allow offline validation.

There is still one step of certificate validation which cannot be really offline, which is the check for the **revocation status**. By definition, revocation is about cancelling a certificate that otherwise looks fine. The three main methods for ascertaining revocation status are:

- CRL: a list of revoked certificate is regularly published by the CA (or another entity to which that power was delegated). The CRL is signed, and valid for some time (a few hours or days).
- OCSP: an duly designated OCSP server can be asked for the current status of a certificate. The *OCSP response* is signed, and has its own validity dates, so an OCSP response is somehow equivalent to a CRL that talks about a single certificate.
- Nothing: for a very long time, Web browsers simply assumed that no certificate was ever revoked, which sure makes the implementation much simpler.

URL for CRL download or for talking to an OCSP server are written in the certificate itself. A system that wants to validate a certificate (your Web browser; a "relying party" in X.509 terminology), and does not use the "nothing" method of revocation check, will want to download a fresh CRL or obtain a fresh OCSP response. However, it may also cache the obtained CRL or OCSP response; Windows, in particular, maintains a CRL cache that is resistant across reboots. Thus, if the browser downloads a CRL, you will see the CRL download on your network traces only once per day or so (depending on the CRL `nextUpdate` field). You can inspect the Windows CRL cache with `certutil -URLcache CRL`. Note that Firefox does its own validation completely independently of the Windows support for certificates.

[OCSP stapling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCSP_stapling) is an SSL/TLS extension by which a client may ask the server to send, as a `CertificateStatus` message, an OCSP response that establishes that the server certificate is not revoked (for now): since OCSP responses are dated and signed, how such a response is obtained has no importance. Since the server can reasonably assume that all clients that talk to it will need the verify the revocation status of the certificate that the server sends, it makes sense to use the server itself as a cache for the relevant OCSP response. It avoids the need for the client to open an extra connection to the OCSP responder, and it makes life easier for the OCSP responder too, because it just have to sign a single fresh response once every few hours.

Not all servers support OCSP stapling, which is why you won't see `CertificateStatus` messages for *all* servers.

Comment: "Note that Firefox does its own validation completely independently of the Windows support for certificates." - what about Chrome/Chromium?(I'm asking this just out of curiosity)

Comment: @JOW, [Chrome gets the CRLs from Google](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2012/02/05/crlsets.html), independently of the OS (and doesn't use OCSP for non-EV certificates).