# How does my computer actually validate a certificate?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

Let's say I receive an email from my friend, X. The email is attached with the digital certifciate of X. Suppose this digital certificate is issued by a company called DS, and my computer does not have this certificate but has a certificate of the company DF, which happens to be the issuer of DS. I want to know how would my computer validate X's certificate if it is a legitimate one or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is an X509 certificate signer verified?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20869/how-is-an-x509-certificate-signer-verified), [Understanding how does certificate validation work](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116264/understanding-how-does-certificate-validation-work)